# Деки С++ Просьба объяснить задание

Tags: c++, очередь

Написать программу копирования одного дэка в другой

Выходит, мне нужно создать двустороннюю очередь, заполнить ее и 
про инициализировать другой, пустой деке?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если бы я был преподавателем (а я был им 10 лет), то в это задание я вложил бы следующий смысл:

Вам нужно показать умение пользоваться структурой данных «дек». У вас есть два дека (например, из STL), один заполнен данными, а другой пустой. Вам нужно написать программу, которая через функции этого дека (которые позволяют обращаться только к крайним элементам) копирует данные из одного дека во второй. При этом важно, что в первом деке в конце работы алгоритма данные должны остаться!

То есть сложность задачи в том, что вы можете обращаться только либо к первому, либо к последнему элементу дека (добавлять или удалять их), но должны как-то перечислить его элементы, копируя их один за другим во второй. Вот такую программу и нужно придумать. При этом я не знаю, можно ли пользоваться готовым деком из STL или тут нужно написать свой.

Надеюсь, я разъяснил задание? Разумеется делать я его не буду.

Comment: Благодарю,на решение я не рассчитывал :)